# Loading Window and Updating UI

Tags: wpf, multithreading

i have drawing app i want when i load saved project to show loading window 
this is common task but i have problem to implement it correctly 
i have tried many ways but it didn't work

note that

1- i want to load file and update the UI (Canvas )

2- i have many Canvases and i Encoder it to Bitmaps but it takes long time i want to Encode it in another thread but as you know i can't modify any object in UI Thread  in another thread

i used BackgroundWorker  and threads with dispatcher but i Got nothing 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

What objects are you loading on the background thread? If they're `Freezable` (such as `BitmapFrame`) then you can `Freeze()` them after loading, thus making them accessible from any thread.

Comment: i want to show loading window when i open the save project 
if you have time please look to this sample 
the first problem was fixed with help of MSDN Forums
http://cid-068215710bef663d.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/DrawingApp2.rar

 thank you